# How to access parent directive's controller by requiring it recursively?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I'm trying to reach the controller of a parent "box" directive recursively:

```
<body ng-app="main">

<!-- no nesting: parent is the just body -->
<box></box>

<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('main', [])
.directive('box', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function() { },
        require: '?^box',  // find optional PARENT "box" directive
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
            // controller should be undefined, as there is no parent box
            alert('Controller found: ' + (controller !== undefined));
        }
    };
});
</script>
</body>
```

I'd expect controller variable to be `undefined` in the link function, but I get the controller of the actual box directive.

So my question is ... how to gain access to the PARENT controller in case like this:

```
<box>
    <box></box>
</box>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gjv9g/1/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OK, found it...

if you want to get hold of the controller of a parent element:

```
...
link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
    // http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element
    // jQuery/jqLite Extras:
    //
    // controller(name) - retrieves the controller of the current element or its parent.
    // By default retrieves controller associated with the ngController directive.
    // If name is provided as camelCase directive name, then the controller for this
    // directive will be retrieved (e.g. 'ngModel').
    var parentCtrl = iElement.parent().controller('box');
}
...
```

This returns either controller of parent directive or, one level higher, the controller of parent's parent directive, If you need to make sure you get a controller of a DIRECT parent, I found this (maybe there is a better solution, I don't know):

```
...
controller: function($scope, $element) {
    // store the element in controller, we'll need it later
    this.$element = $element;
},
// works in both pre and post link functions
link: function() {
    var parentElement = $element.parent();
    var parentCtrl = parentElement.controller('box');

    var hasDirectBoxParent = parentCtrl && parentCtrl.$element[0] === parentElement[0];

}
...
```

Example 1:

```
<box id="a">
    <box id="b"></box>
<box>
```

When the link function is invoked on "box a", parentCtrl is `undefined` in both cases.
When the link function is invoked on "box b", parentCtrl is the controller of "box a" in both cases.

Example 2:

```
<box id="a">
    <div>
        <box id="b"></box>
    </div>
<box>
```

When the link function is invoked on "box a", parentCtrl is `undefined` in both cases.
When the link function is invoked on "box b", parentCtrl is still the controller of "box a" in both cases, but hasDirectBoxParent is `false`, so you can distinguish parent from a grandparent.

Answer (score 39):

Since Angular 1.3 you can use two accents `^^` to search for a directive in parent elements "only".

Quote from the [Angular Docs on `require`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-):

> - `(no prefix)` - Locate the required controller on the current element. Throw an error if not found.
> - `?` - Attempt to locate the required controller or pass null to the link fn if not found.
> - `^` - Locate the
>     required controller by searching the element and its parents. Throw an error if not found.
> - `^^` - Locate the required controller by searching the element's parents. Throw an error if not found.
> - `?^` - Attempt to locate the required controller by searching the element and its parents or pass null to the link fn if not found.
> - `?^^` - Attempt to locate the required controller by searching the element's parents, or pass null to the link fn if not found.

In your case, replace `require: '?^box',` with `require: '?^^box',`

Answer (score 4):

`require` injects the controller from the required (parent) directive in to the current directive (from the angular docs: "require - Require another directive and inject its controller as the fourth argument to the linking function"  http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

So maybe you're already getting what you want?  That is, the parent controller injected in to the children via your `controller` parameter.

Comment: as you can see, there is no PARENT box in my original example, so I'm expecting to get `undefined` as the fourth parameter to the linking function, not the controller of the instance itself

Comment: But you're declaring a controller.  So the parent gets that controller and the children (if any exist) inherit from it.  Is your goal to know if a particular directive is the parent or a child?  If so perhaps you'd like to look at the $parent scope?

Comment: Actually I don't want to use scope in this particular case, as scopes might become tricky, especially if you need to use an isolated scope.
Additionally, best practice is to use controllers and `require` for directive-to-directive communication.
My point is that it works like a charm when you're requiring a parent directive with a different name, why shouldn't you be able to do this recursively.

Comment: Yea, I get where you're coming from.  But I think your life will be easier using a different name for the top level directive.

Comment: One idea, you could declare a variable like `first` in the controller and set it to 1.  The first time through you see that you're the first caller and thus the parent, then set first to 0 so everyone else knows they are a child. It's a little hacky so you may still be happier with 2 different directives.  But thought I'd toss it out just in case.

Comment: this wouldn't work if I had something like this:
    `<box>
        <box></box>
    </box>
    <box></box>`