# Angular - get parent directive's controller in child directive's controller (not link function)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I'm aware how I can get parent's `directive` controller in the child directive's `link` function.
However, I'd prefer to avoid using `link` function (and `$scope` all-together) and have all my code under the `controller` function of the directive.

```js
angular.directive('parent', function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: '/parent.html',
        scope: true,
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: 'parentCtrl',
        controller: function(){
            this.coolFunction = function(){
                console.log('cool');
            }
        }
    }
});

angular.directive('child', function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: '/child.html',
        require: '^parent',
        scope: true,
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: 'childCtrl',
        controller: function() {
            // I want to run coolFunction here.
            // How do I do it?
        }
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: U want to avoid using link? Why?

Comment: I'd like to write code in Angular2-friendly way.

Comment: @Dmitry Sticking to controllers and jqlite (as the answer correctly suggests) will make your code hostile to Angular 2 (which is the opposite of friendly).

Comment: @estus, true, I welcome better answers. At least this solution gets rid of `$scope` and `link` function (-2) vs adding `$element` (-1).

Comment: Replacing the recommended framework workflow with jQuery-ish hack? I would hardly call it a win.

Comment: This feels like you are asking for a solution to a problem that isn't really a problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inject '$element' into the controller and access the parent controller like -

```
  controller: ($element) ->
    var parentCtrl = $element.parent().controller('parent');
    parentCtrl.coolFunction();
    //..........
    //..........
```

This may not be the most transparent way of accessing 'any' parent controller because it requires the specific name of the directive and it is jqlite and not pure Angular.

Found this thread useful - [How to access parent directive's controller by requiring it recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340495/how-to-access-parent-directives-controller-by-requiring-it-recursively?rq=1)

**EDIT:** Thanks to @Dmitry for figuring out that angular doesn't need '.parent' to get the controller.  Updated code -

```
  controller: ($element) ->
    var parentCtrl = $element.controller('parent');
    parentCtrl.coolFunction();
    //..........
```

Comment: that is getting closer to the desired functionality. The only thing I'm not happy with is `$element.parent()` part since child might not be the direct child of the parent, but instead might be a couple levels deep. I suppose I could do a recursive check for the attribute `parent` somehow

Comment: @Dmitry - I am not a fan of using 'parent' references as well. I hope that there's a more elegant way.

Comment: I appreciate your help. It surely made me look in the right direction. After examining [Angular's source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L2005-L2042) it seems that calling `.parent` isn't necessary. I actually tried it and it worked without `.parent`. Update your answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

The proper pattern for that would be

```
app.directive('child', function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: '/child.html',
        require: ['child', '^parent'],
        scope: true,
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: 'childCtrl',
        controller: function() {
            this.coolFunction = function () {
                this._parent.coolFunction();
            }
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
            var childCtrl = ctrls[0];
            var parentCtrl = ctrls[1];
            childCtrl._parent = parentCtrl;
        }
    }
});
```

The bad thing is that `_parent` is being exposed to scope with `controllerAs`, but it will rarely be a problem.

Notice that you won't have access to parent controller from child until `link` glues them together. Which is fine as long as you use parent controller in child methods.

Controller provides methods and initial properties to view model (and it does it cleaner with controllerAs), link glues the stuff, that's how directives work.

Both `$scope` and `link` have their purposes in Angular 1.x and are indispensable even with latest community developments. Banishing them for no valid reason is overzealous and may lead to bad design solutions. The absence of 'link' and 'scope' words in code won't help to make the app easier to port to 2.x. Though learning Angular 2 now and developing proper habits for 1.x will.

Answer (score 0):

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21252383/4420532) or [here](https://work.karlhorky.com/frontend-tricks/angular-1-inject-required-directive-controller-into-directive-controller/)

1. `var parentForm = $element.inheritedData('$formController') || ....`
2. `var parentForm = $element.controller('form')`