# Require a directive's controller that is nested in a parent directive, AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

I'm wondering if there is a way to require the controller of a directive that exists/is nested somewhere as a common parent's child directive in AngularJS.

### Directive Structure

Suppose I have the following structure for my directives:

```
<parent-directive>
    <ul>
        <li some-nested-directive ng-repeat="dir in directives"></li>
    </ul>
    <settings-menu></settings-menu>
</parent-directive>
```

### Directive Definition

```
/* 
* some-nested-directive directive definition
*/
.directive('someNestedDirective', function(){
    // ...
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       controller: someNestedDirectiveController
    };
});

/* 
* settings-menu directive definition
*/
.directive('settingsMenu', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: [], // how to require the nested-directive controller here?
        link: function(scope, iElement, attrs, ctrls){
            // ...
        }
    };
})
```

I've already checked out *[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340495/how-to-access-parent-directives-controller-by-requiring-it-recursively)* SO question which states how to require controllers of directives that exist along the same line in a hierarchy.

But my question is regarding ***a way to do the same in a hierarchy of directives that NOT necessarily exist along the same line***. And if this is not possible, what is a proper workaround for it. Any help would be appreciated.

***EDIT***

Also, can any of the prefixes for `require` (or a combination of them) be used to achieve the same?

Comment: Have you considered using service to communicate between the directives? Because as far as I know there no direct way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use `parent` directive as a way to pass references between controllers:

```js
var mod = angular.module('test', []);

mod.directive('parent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div>Parent <div ng-transclude=""></div></div>',
    controller: function ParentCtrl() {}
  }
});

mod.directive('dirA', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>Dir A <input type="text" ng-model="name"></div>',
    require: ['dirA', '^^parent'],
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
      //here we store this directive controller into parent directive controller instance
      ctrls[1].dirA = ctrls[0];
    },
    controller: function DirACtrl($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'Dir A Name';
      this.name = function() {
        return $scope.name;
      };
    }
  }
});

mod.directive('dirB', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>Dir A <button ng-click="click()">Click</button></div>',
    require: ['dirB', '^^parent'],
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
      //let's assign parent controller instance to this directive controller instance
      ctrls[0].parent = ctrls[1];
    },
    controller: function DirBCtrl($scope) {
      var ctrl = this;
      $scope.click = function() {
        //access dirA controller through parent
        alert(ctrl.parent.dirA.name());
      };
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app='test'>
  <parent>
    <dir-a></dir-a>
    <dir-b></dir-b>
  </parent>
</div>
```

When using above approach it also makes sense to encapsulate how the `dirA` controller is stored inside `parent` controller i.e. by using [a getter property](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) or by exposing only the required properties of `dirA` controller.

Comment: Its good approach, but would you think a service will be better to communicate?

Comment: Using service may work also but you have to remember that you have to remember that service is basically a singleton so it's going to be harder to use when there are many instances of directives.

Comment: Yes, I know that the services are singleton. So you can take the benefit and create messaging service by using Pub/Sub design pattern and control the communication between the directives. And if you don't want to create the messaging service, you can use angular $broadcast/$emit to achieve the same thing.

Comment: You can use Pub/Sub but I can't imagine a simple solution where you would have 4 instances of directives and you would only like them to communicate in pairs (DirA_1, DirB_1 under Parent 1) and (DirA_2, DirB_2 under Parent B).

Comment: In your case **(DirA_1, DirB_1 under Parent 1)**, basically use require property in both **DirA_1, Die_B** to get there parent controller because they are in the same hierarchy. But what I understand from the question is imagine your example **(DirA_1, DirB_1 under Parent 1)** and there is another directive not nested under the parent and want to require the controller of one of the directives that are nested under it. That's why I suggest to use service like messaging. take a look at the plunker I made. https://plnkr.co/edit/R6hXCY4XmLMUhtpl7OSQ?p=preview

Comment: I don't see where the question suggest that there's yet another directive (apart from DirA, DirB and parent). If this is really the case then you're right that using a service might be the only solution - however it's not going to be as simple as the example you prepared because of the case where you have multiple instances of pair of directives .

Comment: You are right, I got confused with the bold part in the question. So your approach is good.

Answer (score 0):

I aggree with miensol's reply and I recommend that approach but in some cases you may need something like that;

```
<parent-directive>
<ul>
    <some-nested-directive id="snd1" ng-repeat="dir in directives"></some-nested-directive>
</ul>
<settings-menu some-nested-directive-id="snd1"></settings-menu>
```

You can access the scope of some-nested-directive using its id from the settings-menu;

```
$("#" + scope.someNestedDirectiveId).scope()
```

Once I used this approach to cascade the values of a dropdown according to the choise of another independent dropdown.